# Generic Attribute C#10

Tags: c#, generics, attributes

I understand that in the C#10 new features that I'm able to create Generic Attributes, however despite setting the target framework to .NET 6.0 the compiler is still throwing the [CS0698](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0698?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0698)) error.

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2019 but as far as I know having the SDK installed should allow me to utilize this feature, additionally I have preview features enabled but still no luck

[image]
[image]

I saw a user mention this in a comment, but I still can't get it to work
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69949881/17399588

How can I get this to work?

EDIT: Have tried Flydog57's answer but am still getting the same issues

Comment: From: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10: _""_Additional features are available in preview mode. You're encouraged to try these features and provide feedback on them. They may change before their final release. In order to use these features, you must set <LangVersion> to Preview in your project. Read about Generic attributes later in this article."_ And then, when you find `Generic Attributes`, it has this: _"Generic attributes is a preview feature. You must set <LangVersion> to Preview to enable this feature. This feature may change before its final release."_

Comment: I've done this but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: You probably want to mention that in the question.

Comment: Apologies, I just tried this and edited the post